# Получить данные между тегами в html страницы

Tags: python, парсер

Делаю так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('site.ru')
html = response.read()
```

Получаю исходный код страницы. И как мне теперь получить данные между конретными тегами?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Дальше нужно использовать парсер разметки. Я рекомендую [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). С ним код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a')  # все ссылки на странице
print links[0].get_text()  # текст первой ссылки
print links[0].attrs['href']  # куда ведёт первая ссылка
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, есть достаточно способов: библиотеки BeutifulSoup, lxml, xml, регулярные выражения, в конце-концов, - смотря, что конкретно вам нужно. Если стоит задача выдернуть какой-то специфический тег, то можно обойтись регуляркой, если поставлена задача отпарсить странице целиком... Впрочем, на эту тему масса ответов в сети.